# Semiconductors: electrons more mobile than holes despite being heavier?

Tags: semiconductors, solid-state-devices

I apologize if this is a very basic question. But I have always known it to be true that in Silicon, electrons have higher mobility than holes. From my semiconductor physics classes in first year, the thing I recalled was that mobility is inversely related to effective mass for the basic scattering model. So I assumed that electrons being more mobile must have lower effective mass. This is wrong as I learned going through the material again: electrons have HIGHER EFFECTIVE MASS than holes. So is there any explanation for this? Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Physics stack

Comment: Here's the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(solid-state_physics)) on your topic. There, you can find that the electron can have 'negative mass'. Are you referring to this description?

Comment: @jonk no the electron cannot have negative mass

Comment: @Neil_UK Sorry, but I don't agree. In the help center it's stated that *the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces* are on topic, and arguably solid state physics as employed in electronic devices falls under that category. Moreover, semiconductor behavior is a topic commonly taught at university in Electronic Engineering courses (at least here in Italy). So closing is not the right action here. OTOH, I may agree that the OP could get better answers at PHY.SE just because more experts of the field may well be dwell there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mobility is proportional to a scattering time and inversely proportional to a quasiparticle mass. The explanation you are looking for is simple:  in silicon, a **lower hole mass** is outweighed by a **higher scattering time of electron quasiparticles** in lattice.

Comment: thanks. I was assuming a parameter to be constant when it is not. However, Im confused. You mean the scattering time of holes is LOWER right? because mobility is proportional to the scattering time?

Comment: Oh, sorry, corrected. Thank you.